# Unable to import ActiveDirectory Module

Tags: powershell, module, active-directory

In-place upgrade of Win10 1607 to 1703 and seems to have broke loading ActiveDirectory module.

Get below when attempting to import the module:
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Works fine and loads other modules listed in my profile:
powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules

Found posts suggesting reinstall old v1607 RSAT snapin, but doesn't fix

https://www.handheldgroup.com/support-rugged-computers/knowledgebase-KB/22996/

```
Running:
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      5.1.15063.608                                                                                                                          
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                
BuildVersion                   10.0.15063.608                                                                                                                         
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                        
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Creator does wonderful things. I recommend just re-installing if you can. And I hope you're just running the module on your win10 not the whole AD?

Comment: Re-installing the entire 1703 OS in other words?  Seems like a major hassle and time suck :-( Not understanding 'running on Win10, not the whole AD'? Trying to load the module on my win10 workstation to query against & admin AD as I always have. Appeciate the reply!

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveDirectory` module comes from the Active Directory RSAT tools.

RSAT is always version specific, so any upgrade of Windows (previously this was going to new major versions, now with Windows 10 it includes the new builds), means you will have to reinstall RSAT tools after the upgrade.

Once you do that you should have the `ActiveDirectory` module once again.

Comment: Hi - yeah did so already.  Many posts out there mention there is no 1703 ver RSAT released, so I re-installed the 1607 version, but didnt work. http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2017/04/microsoft-will-not-be-releasing-remote-server-admin-tools-rsat-for-windows-10-redstone-2/

Comment: @Deinck this process has worked for me, but maybe some ar ehaving issues with it. If so, it may be that you need a support call with Microsoft.

Comment: ok, ugh.  will try and report back with my finds.  Appreciate it!

Comment: I believe Windows 10 RSAT 1.2 works on both 1607/1703. Where 1.1 worked on 1507/1511.

Comment: @BenH it does, but you still have to reinstall it.

Comment: found this awesome little script and it shows suces, I reboot, but still no luck. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Install-the-Active-fd32e541